# ZFS/ZPOOL: How to safely "reassemble" a pool?

Tags: zfs

I have a setup with a smaller boot/root SSD drive and two HDDs organised into a mirror zpool, which I created as follows:

```
zpool create megastorage mirror /dev/sdb /dev/sdc

zfs create megastorage/large
zfs set mountpoint=/home/sergey/large megastorage/large

zfs create megastorage/Photos
zfs set mountpoint=/home/sergey/Photos megastorage/Photos

zfs create megastorage/Videos
zfs set mountpoint=/home/sergey/Videos megastorage/Videos

zfs create megastorage/Downloads
zfs set mountpoint=/home/sergey/Downloads megastorage/Downloads
```

It all was working fine until (at my own risk, blah blah, I know :) ) I upgraded my machine from Kubuntu 22.10 to 23.04 dev (the new KDE tiling support is awesome btw).

Now it appears that ZFS configuration has been "reset" - the drives/partitions are still there:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 7.28 TiB, 8001563222016 bytes, 15628053168 sectors
Disk model: ST8000DM004-2U91
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: D84C712C-9C3C-D547-A67E-1F98349ECAB6

Device           Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1         2048 15628036095 15628034048  7.3T Solaris /usr & Apple ZFS
/dev/sda9  15628036096 15628052479       16384    8M Solaris reserved 1


Disk /dev/sdb: 7.28 TiB, 8001563222016 bytes, 15628053168 sectors
Disk model: ST8000DM004-2U91
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 2D33AD17-386C-CE4D-8623-ACFE852D090A

Device           Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1         2048 15628036095 15628034048  7.3T Solaris /usr & Apple ZFS
/dev/sdb9  15628036096 15628052479       16384    8M Solaris reserved 1
```

However, it appears that zpool no longer has any information about the drives:

```
# zpool list
no pools available
```

All the mountpoints are now just empty folders.

How do I safely recreate the pool and re-add the drives without erasing the data? The manpages do not make it clear whether `zpool create` would erase the data on the drives.

Also, out of curiosity, where is the configuration of the pool is stored? The first time I did it it just worked like magic without tweaking any configs to make the changes permanent.

Comment: Maybe the pools are just exported, did you try: `zpool import`

Comment: @freezed: Oh, ok, "exporting" was a concept I wasn't familiar with. I ran `zpool import megastorage` and then `zfs set mountpoint=...` for each mountpoint and my files are back now, thanks. If you add your comment as an answer I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the pools are just exported, did you try: `zpool import`